# How can I read a local css file to inject it into a react-native WebView?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-fs, react-native-webview

In my react-native app, I want to inject css into pages loaded by react-native `WebView`. (I am displaying online websites that should look slightly different within my app's `WebView` than they would normally)

The most promising approach I found so far would be to inject javascript (this can be done easily with the `WebView`'s `injectedJavaScript` property) which is doing the following:

1. Read a css file that lies in my app's src folder (I really want it to be there because I consider it to be part of my project) into a string.
2. Generate a `<style>...</style>` tag from that
3. Write it into the document's `<head>`.

Do you think that approach would work? So far I could not accomplish step 1. I have tried to use `react-native-fs` to read my css file but could not figure out how I can access an existing file from my app's src folder. I guess I would have to export it somehow so it ends up in `RNFS.MainBundlePath` or `RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath`?